# linking html web page to text editor to practice

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to link this page http://www.bauer.uh.edu/parks/f1471m.htm to my text editor ( text mate) with a mac.

I even copied the code and pasted it into an HTML file, and made a .js file (the one I'm trying to use to practice with) in the same folder and to use the local tag with no success.

I tried using src="http://www.bauer.uh.edu/parks/f1471m.htm" with no luck.

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What sort of problem are you having with it? It is not quite clear what you want right now. Try editing your question.

Comment: thank you very much. I figured it out. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions here...

From what you're describing, I think you're trying to directly edit the file. Unless you have write access on that server, what you're doing isn't going to work. Some web development software will allow you to do this, but most text editors don't.

Can you work on the file locally (on your computer's file system) and upload it to the server through FTP?

Many browsers give you the ability to save a page locally these days. That would set up the proper structure for you on your own machine. (FireFox can do this using Save Page)